# Create buttons for this dynamic values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and controller returns some dynamic values.I need to create buttons for that dynamic values.

My Contoller

```
 public ActionResult LoginAs()
        {
            string[] roles = (string[])TempData["data"]; // this array returns 3 values.I need to create a buttons for that values.

            return View();
        }
```

I have no idea how to create a buttons for this dynamic values.mvc

Comment: What you mean by 'buttons for'? Buttons value? Name?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**
(Buttons type changed to `string[]`)

Model

```
public class LoginAsViewModel
{
   public string[] Buttons {get;set;}
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult LoginAs()
{
    //I don't know what TempData returns       
    string[] roles = (string[])TempData["data"]; 
    var model = new LoginAsViewModel
    {
        Buttons = (string[])TempData["data"]
    };
    return View(model );
}
```

View

```
@model LoginAsViewModel

@for(int i=0; i < Model.Buttons.Count(); i++)
{
    <button>@Model.Buttons[i]</button>
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error : Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer

Comment: Yes.thats correct.Is ther any method to give a links to that dynamic generated buttons ?

Comment: There are no such methods but you can use the same technique that I used to set button text